# How to reshape a CVXPY variable for constraint calculation?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I have an integer variable named `running_times` which is length `N`.

Each index in this variable represents the running time required for each period over a 24 hour period.

I need to perform a calculation against some data which has the shape `(48,)` `this represents 30 minute periods over the 24 hour period`

I wish to perform a reshape/similar on my variable to help reshape this to `(48,)`
Assume max running times (in minutes) of the following:
`[480 360 120 180 90 120 90]`

Say we have `running_time` variable with output (in minutes) `[231 159 0 0 44 99 90]`

I would want to reshape the above output into a matrix of possibly flow as I know the flow rate per second is 9.6.

I would expect an array/vector with something like below to help with my calculation (480/30) for length, 231*(9.6*60) == total for period, the period is split into 30 minute segments not that due to the last running time being not % 30 it is a fraction of the rest:
`[17200 17200 17200 17200 17200 17200 17200 12016 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

This would be repeated to give a (48,) shape vector for comparison with my other array.

Is there something I am missing with this linear programming problem?

Comment: I don't see how this is a linear programming problem. It isn't clear to me what you are trying do do